# How to disable/setup same name and same password authentication between two windows PCs on the same network?

Tags: authentication, networking, windows-authentication, dcom, windows-networking

So I set up a simple network with two computers. Both of them are in the same Workgroup.

- I Created a LOCAL user 'A' with password 'A' in Computer 1.
- And then I created an identical named LOCAL user 'A' with identical password 'A' on Computer 2.

What I notice is that when I'm logged in as 'A' in computer 2, I am allowed network access as 'A' in Computer 1. E.g. when browsing 'A' shared folders.

This is ironic as even though they are the identical in name, they are actually two different LOCAL users on two different computers!

This to me can be a security hazard. What if coincidentally a person has the same username and password in computer 2 thus incorrectly given access to Computer 1?

**My Question:**

- What is this sharing of username and password called?
- How do we enable/disable this sharing of identical LOCAL usernames and passwords between two computers?

I've also realized that this works during DCOM calls as well.

Thank you for any answers

Comment: Valid question, but off topic.  You should ask on superuser

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of Windows?

Comment: BTW SuUper user is only for Linux.... nobody entertains windows questions

Comment: @user1034912: You clearly have your SE sites mixed up. SU is most certainly not restricted to Linux questions. Also, next time wait for your question to be migrated instead of posting a duplicate on another SE site.

Comment: Crossposts: [1. @1:37](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16350301/revisions), [2. @1:37](https://superuser.com/questions/590948/how-to-disable-setup-same-name-and-same-password-authentication-between-two-wind?noredirect=1&lq=1), [3. @2:00](https://superuser.com/questions/590864/how-to-disable-setup-same-name-and-same-password-authentication-between-two-wind), [4. @3:34](https://serverfault.com/questions/504662/how-come-identical-name-and-authentication-between-two-windows-pcs-on-same-netwo)